# $\{ X_n \}$ is a sequence such that $\vert X_{n+1} - X_n \vert \lt \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n$. Then show that $\{ X_n \}$ is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

$\{ X_n \}$ is a sequence such that $\vert X_{n+1} - X_n \vert \lt \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n$. Then show that $\{ X_n \}$ is Cauchy.

I know that I want to show:

$\vert X_{m} - X_n \vert \lt \varepsilon$ for all $m,n \geq k$

I also know:

$m>n, |X_m - X_n| < 1/2^{m-1} + 1/2^{m-2} + \cdots+1/2^n$

Comment: Please use mathJax and provide the full problem. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: For m>n, |Xm - Xn| < 1/2^m-1 + 1/2^m-2 +......+1/2^n

Comment: @Learner_ Please **edit your question** to tell us what you've tried.  Don't put that information in the comments.

Comment: okay, my hint would be to factor out $1/2^{m-1}$ and then apply the geometric series formulas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+...  $(Why?)

You can now bound your sum and find the desired $k$ without worrying about $m$.